# What is Ethereum's hash input data size?

Tags: gpu

I'm testing https://github.com/mjosaarinen/tiny_sha3 project on my machine with GPGPU features of https://github.com/tugrul512bit/Cekirdekler and it successfully hashes a single byte correctly in a single thread as same as in https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_512.html.

Now I need to test for speed to know how many hashes per second. What is the input data size? Single char as I just did? 32 bytes? 1kB? 100kB? 10x1kB? 32x10kB? NxM bytes? What are N and M?

I see everywhere that the metric is million hashes per second but with what size of input data?